# How to crypt data of JHIPSTER application directly in JDL?

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

Is there a simple way to say directly in the JDL of a JHISPter application that a given field is crypted?
How to configure the application to crypt data of a specific field of an entity?
with Spring, and for instance Jasypt, Bouncy Castle.
It will be great to have additional JDL tags?
Thanks for your advice.

References:

- in french https://www.sodifrance.fr/blog/jasypt-bouncy-castle-hibernate-et-spring-simplifier-la-cryptographie-en-java/
- JDL http://easynode.github.io/jdl/#annexes

Comment: No it's not possible in JDL